# Flash banners won't display in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, flash

I have 9 .swf banners that I want to display on a page in wordpress. I've uploaded them fine with the help of an addition to the theme's function.php file. They won't display though. I've Googled but still can't find an answer.

Comment: I doubt you will get help unless you post the URLs to your website. It could be pretty much everything - the way swfs are embedded to the website, flash player versions or browser versions that not support flash plugins by default

Comment: Many of the modern browsers now block Flash by default. Are you sure your browser has Flash enabled?